# In Mathematica, is there a way to set a variable to the lowest value in a matrix?

Tags: matrices, mathematica, searching

It seems that a major aspect of this question is figuring out whether or not I can search the matrix and compare values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is a matrix, Min[A] gives the smallest entry.